# android button text and html

Tags: android, html, button

how do I use `html` in an android widget Button?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to use `Html.fromHtml()` to convert raw HTML into a `Spanned` object that you can use in a `setText()` call on your button. As the `Html` documentation states, "Not all HTML tags are supported".

Comment: is there a way to do it without using Java code?  I have static text encoded in a resource file:
<Button
android:id="@+id/x_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/x"

</Button>

<resources>
     <string name="x"><p>XX</p>YY</string>
</resources>

Comment: You should be able to use the same method call that @commonsware.com used, and just get the string from the resource file. Context.getString(R.id.x) should be it

Answer (score 3):

Mark's answer is spot on, as usual. Here is a more complete example for reference though (this is a confusing part of the docs). (And, yes, I know this example isn't using a `Button`, but this is the one I had handy, and it's the same idea.)

String needs to be a resource:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
    <string name="mystring">    
        You can use regular text, and escaped HTML markup
        &lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;
        A simple BOLD example &lt;b&gt;StackOverflow&lt;/b&gt;.
    </string>
    </resources>
```

Then get the resource and use `Html.fromHtml()` (if you are using an `EditText`, you also need to make sure the buffer is set to SPANNABLE):

```
 public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    TextView myTextView;

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.about);     

          myTextView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.mytextview);
          myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.mystring)),
                             TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
       }  
       ...
```

Lastly, note that all HTML doesn't work, of course. So depending on your requirements, this might not be entirely useful. Also see this [issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2219) if you try to  use a link (anchor tag) and you want it to respond to being clicked. For simple stuff, see [Linkify](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html).

Answer (score 1):

These two answers are also valid, you can also do it like this.  I was trying to do something of the same nature and found out that my html along with CSS was not getting formatted correctly so I took the string and loaded it into a webview like this:

```
 WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.MyWebview);
 String summary = "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body></html>";
 webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

and it recognized all the styles and formatted the html correctly.  More from the android reference [HERE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)