# write multiline text on button

Tags: android, button, text, formatting

I am working on a keyboard application in android, and I have a small
problem when writing text on a button.

I am trying to do something like this:

[image]

I have one solution. My string.xml is:

```
<string name="multiplelines">q \n1\t|</string>
```

In my keyboard.xml:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/xQ" android:text="@string/multiplelines"/>
```

My output is like this:

[image]

So, my question is:

1. How can I give different colors and text sizes to different text on the same button?
2. Is this the right way to use css in android?

Comment: I don't know if it will work, but you might want to look at `SpannableString` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html

Comment: `button.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='black'>q</font><br/><font color='blue'><small>1</small></font><font color='red'><small>|</small></font>"));` This does the trick with the colors, and the second line characters are somewhat smaller.

Comment: @Eri your solution solved my problem, but i have one more issue related with use of button,As you see on first image, i need the alphabet('q') is in top left corner on button, number('1') in place of 'q' and '|' at his same place.I tried to use margin attribute in above syntax but it's not working...

Comment: It seems like android buttons does not fully support all html attributes. However you might be able to do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4867756/1302697).