# Android Button with text+®

Tags: android, button

I´m trying to do a simple buttom that include a text(company name)+R(registered symbol) but I also need that the R will be superscript of the text, something like this:
http://www.geofonica.com/graphics/gf-logo.gif

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: There is no unicode value for that registered symbol in superscript.

Comment: yes I can´t make registered symbol superscript inside the buttom

Comment: Refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522337/unicode-characters-not-displayed-in-textview-settext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you actually have the code I think you can do it as follows:

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(Html.fromHtml("<sup>&#174;</sup>"));
```

Otherwise, I think it might be acceptable to just assume a superscript R.

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(Html.fromHtml("<sup>R</sup>"));
```

Hope it helps.

Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/commontasks.html#selectingtext

Answer (score 2):

> html code for superscript registered trademark symbol to show like Google®

```
 <string name=company_name">Company name<sup>&#174;</sup></string>
```

> and in your text view

```
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_company"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/company_name"/>
```

> And then use the method Html.fromHtml()

Answer (score 0):

Use the html code for "registered trade mark sign", &#174

to display something like: 
Company name ®

Two ways to achieve this:

1) add into your `strings.xml` file

```
<string name=company_name">Company name &#174;</string>
```

and load that string to your layout

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_company"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/company_name"/>
```

2) Use the method `Html.fromHtml()`

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(Html.fromHtml("Company name &#174;"));
```

Comment: OP wants the (R) to be superscripted.

Comment: yes Eleanasys superscripted smaller and up to company name .

Answer (score 0):

Using `Html.fromHtml` you can display html (at least a subset) in TextView, Button etc...

A good example can be found at [android button text and html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127757/android-button-text-and-html)

For the registered symbol you can encode it as html entity ® `&#174;`

For displaying the symbol in superscript you can use the html tag `<sup></sup>`